# Watson Assistant -- Prompting for required slot not working

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-dialog, watson-assistant

I have this node on the dialog tree of my Watson Assistant

[image]

So this node should be triggered when an entity @courses with either the value course or math is found.

In case the value of the entity courses is course but not math then the slot still needs to be filled and should prompt the user with 'Which specific course are you referring to?' since the slot is required. The problem I'm having is that the prompt is not getting triggered as shown in this image

[image]

So the entity courses with the value course is correctly identified but the prompt is not triggered.w

Am I missing something?

*Edit*

[image]

So modifying the configuration of the slot to add conditional responses I added a conditional response if the value of @courses:math is not found. Notice that I'm checking for the value of @courses:math on the black marked area but then I check on the conditional response if it is not found (red area) and if the value @courses:course is found and then the response should be triggered. So the conditional response should be something like

```
if @courses:course exists and @courses:math doesn't exist then
    print "What specific course are you referring to?"
else if (@courses:course exists and @courses:math exists) or @courses:math exists then
    do something else
```

But this is still not triggering any response for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to configure the slot further.

Click the cog out to the side (between required and the trash can). You should see a modal appear that looks similar to the screen shot below. Click the dot dot dot menu at the top and click "Enable Conditional Responses". This will change the modal a bit so you can check the value of the entity. In the screenshot you can see I tested it, and the behavior appears to be what you are looking for.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the behavior I want is a bit different than what you showed. Notice how I want to trigger a response if the courses:math value is not found, not if the courses:course value is found. I think your configuration will be triggered on the latter but not on the former which is what I need because I need a value for courses:math. I now configured it so that if courses:math is not found it will ask for it but it isn't working still. I will edit my OP to show what I did on the configuration area.